# wide char and win32::api

Tags: perl, winapi

In perl I'm using this code to call the shellabout dialog using win32::api:

```
my $shellAbout = Win32::API->new('Shell32', 'int ShellAboutA(HWND hWnd, LPCTSTR szApp, LPCTSTR szOtherStuff, HICON hIcon)');  
    $shellAbout->Call (0, 'perl-reguser', 'Editor del registro de usuario', 0);
```

The above works as expected, but when I try to use the unicode version of shellabout:

```
my $shellAbout = Win32::API->new('Shell32', 'int ShellAboutW(HWND hWnd, LPCTSTR szApp, LPCTSTR szOtherStuff, HICON hIcon)');  
    $shellAbout->Call (0, 'perl-reguser', 'Editor del registro de usuario', 0);
```

The strings are not displayed. I have the following declared:

```
use utf8;
use Encode;
# ..
binmode (STDOUT, ":encoding(utf8)");
```

any ideas?

Comment: The Windows API uses UTF-16.

Comment: Same result using **binmode (STDOUT, ":encoding(UTF-16)")**

Comment: STDOUT has nothing to do with it.  Try encoding the two strings you are passing in UTF-16

Comment: ok, I still getting the same results with: **use Encode qw/encode/;** and **my $desc = encode ('UTF-16', 'Editor del registro de usuario');**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `W` calls, `LPCTSTR` must be a NUL-terminated string encoded using UTF-16le.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use utf8;   # Source code is encoded using UTF-8.

use Encode     qw( encode );
use Win32::API qw( );

my $shellAbout;

sub ShellAbout {
   my ($hWnd, $szApp, $szOtherStuff, $hIcon) = @_;

   $shellAbout ||= Win32::API->new('Shell32', 'int ShellAboutW(HWND hWnd, LPCTSTR szApp, LPCTSTR szOtherStuff, HICON hIcon)');

   $szApp = encode('UTF-16le', $szApp . "\0");
   $szOtherStuff = encode('UTF-16le', $szOtherStuff . "\0") if defined($szOtherStuff);

   $hWnd  //= 0;
   $hIcon //= 0;   

   return $shellAbout->Call($hWnd, $szApp, $szOtherStuff, $hIcon);
}


ShellAbout(undef, 'perl-reguser', 'Editor del registro de usuario', undef)
   or die($^E);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip :)