# Handling wide char values returned by Win32::API

Tags: perl, winapi

The answer provided in [wide char and win32::api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32425948/wide-char-and-win32api) works for *passing* utf-16 to the Win API. But how do I convert utf16 strings *returned* by the Win API? (I am trying to use `GetCommandLineW`).

I have tried both `Unicode::String` and `Encode::decode` without success. I'm guessing that perhaps the data needs to be packed or unpacked first, but how?

After that, the next problem is how to deal with a pointer-to-pointer-to-utf16 like the one returned by `CommandLineToArgvW`.

Comment: Please post code of what you tried, what you expected, and what you got instead.

Comment: @andlabs, I understand the question, and I know there's really not much more the OP could provide. I'm in the middle of writing an answer.

Comment: *"I have tried both `Unicode::String` and `Encode::decode`"* Please include the code to show exactly what you tried and describe the problems you had. It will help us to write more accurate answers, and your question's primary value is to the many other people who may be looking for a solution to a similar  problem. "Without success" isn't much of a problem statement and it will be impossible to tell whether your situation is a match with just that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you specify the return value is a string, Win32::API assumes it's a terminated by a byte with value 0, but bytes with that value are common in UTF-16le text.

As Win32::API suggests, you should use the `N` type (or `Q` on 64-bit builds) to get the pointer as a number, then read the pointed memory yourself. Win32::API's provides `ReadMemory` to read memory, but it requires knowing how much memory to read. That's not useful for NUL-terminated strings and wide NUL-terminated strings.

For wide NUL-terminated strings, Win32::API provides `SafeReadWideCString`. But `SafeReadWideCString` can return a string unrelated to the input on error, so I use my own `decode_LPCWSTR` instead.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say state );

use open ':std', ':encoding('.do { require Win32; "cp".Win32::GetConsoleOutputCP() }.')';

use Config     qw( %Config );
use Encode     qw( decode encode );
use Win32::API qw( ReadMemory );

use constant PTR_SIZE => $Config{ptrsize};

use constant PTR_PACK_FORMAT =>
     PTR_SIZE == 8 ? 'Q'
   : PTR_SIZE == 4 ? 'L'
   : die("Unrecognized ptrsize\n");

use constant PTR_WIN32API_TYPE =>
     PTR_SIZE == 8 ? 'Q'
   : PTR_SIZE == 4 ? 'N'
   : die("Unrecognized ptrsize\n");

    
sub lstrlenW {
   my ($ptr) = @_;

   state $lstrlenW = Win32::API->new('kernel32', 'lstrlenW', PTR_WIN32API_TYPE, 'i')
      or die($^E);

   return $lstrlenW->Call($ptr);
}


sub decode_LPCWSTR {
   my ($ptr) = @_;
   return undef if !$ptr;

   my $num_chars = lstrlenW($ptr)
      or return '';

   return decode('UTF-16le', ReadMemory($ptr, $num_chars * 2));
}


# Returns true on success. Returns false and sets $^E on error.
sub LocalFree {
   my ($ptr) = @_;

   state $LocalFree = Win32::API->new('kernel32', 'LocalFree', PTR_WIN32API_TYPE, PTR_WIN32API_TYPE)
      or die($^E);

   return $LocalFree->Call($ptr) == 0;
}


sub GetCommandLine {
   state $GetCommandLine = Win32::API->new('kernel32', 'GetCommandLineW', '', PTR_WIN32API_TYPE)
      or die($^E);

   return decode_LPCWSTR($GetCommandLine->Call());
}


# Returns a reference to an array on success. Returns undef and sets $^E on error.
sub CommandLineToArgv {
   my ($cmd_line) = @_;

   state $CommandLineToArgv = Win32::API->new('shell32', 'CommandLineToArgvW', 'PP', PTR_WIN32API_TYPE)
      or die($^E);

   my $cmd_line_encoded = encode('UTF-16le', $cmd_line."\0");
   my $num_args_buf = pack('i', 0);  # Allocate space for an "int".

   my $arg_ptrs_ptr = $CommandLineToArgv->Call($cmd_line_encoded, $num_args_buf)
      or return undef;

   my $num_args = unpack('i', $num_args_buf);
   my @args =
      map { decode_LPCWSTR($_) }
         unpack PTR_PACK_FORMAT.'*',
            ReadMemory($arg_ptrs_ptr, PTR_SIZE * $num_args);

   LocalFree($arg_ptrs_ptr);
   return \@args;
}


{
   my $cmd_line = GetCommandLine();

   say $cmd_line;

   my $args = CommandLineToArgv($cmd_line)
      or die("CommandLineToArgv: $^E\n");

   for my $arg (@$args) {
      say "<$arg>";
   }
}
```

Comment: Fixed so it's correct for both 32-bit and 64-bit builds of Perl.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a clear and useful implementation. It shows nicely the concepts needed to effectively use Win32::API. I wrote a replacement for decode_LPCWSTR() that is probably efficient enough for most purposes: 
`code`
 sub decode_LPCWSTR {

   state $lstrlenW = Win32::API->new('kernel32', 'lstrlenW', PTR_WIN32API_TYPE, 'N')
      or die($^E);

   my ($ptr) = @_;
   return undef if !$ptr;

   my $nchars = $lstrlenW->Call($ptr);
   return '' if $nchars == 0;

   my $sW = ReadMemory($ptr, $nchars * 2);
   return decode('UTF-16le', $sW);   
}

Comment: Indeed. I shall replace the one in my answer with that!

Comment: (Can someone please format my response and then delete this? I couldn't get "`code`" to work. Thanks.)

Comment: 1) We can't edit comments, 2) Can't format code in comments. 3) It's been incorporated into my answer, so its readability in the comments is moot.