# Par::Packer packaged scripts lose the ability to parse UTF-8 arguments from the command line

Tags: perl, utf-8, command-line-arguments

The answer provided in ["Handling wide char values returned by Win32::API"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44488898/handling-wide-char-values-returned-by-win32api/44489228#44489228) can parse UTF-8 command line arguments on windows.

But with Par Packer packaging, the parsing failed.

If I save this code

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say state );

use open ':std', ':encoding('.do { require Win32; "cp".Win32::GetConsoleOutputCP() }.')';

use Config     qw( %Config );
use Encode     qw( decode encode );
use Win32::API qw( ReadMemory );

use constant PTR_SIZE => $Config{ptrsize};

use constant PTR_PACK_FORMAT =>
     PTR_SIZE == 8 ? 'Q'
   : PTR_SIZE == 4 ? 'L'
   : die("Unrecognized ptrsize\n");

use constant PTR_WIN32API_TYPE =>
     PTR_SIZE == 8 ? 'Q'
   : PTR_SIZE == 4 ? 'N'
   : die("Unrecognized ptrsize\n");

    
sub lstrlenW {
   my ($ptr) = @_;

   state $lstrlenW = Win32::API->new('kernel32', 'lstrlenW', PTR_WIN32API_TYPE, 'i')
      or die($^E);

   return $lstrlenW->Call($ptr);
}


sub decode_LPCWSTR {
   my ($ptr) = @_;
   return undef if !$ptr;

   my $num_chars = lstrlenW($ptr)
      or return '';

   return decode('UTF-16le', ReadMemory($ptr, $num_chars * 2));
}


# Returns true on success. Returns false and sets $^E on error.
sub LocalFree {
   my ($ptr) = @_;

   state $LocalFree = Win32::API->new('kernel32', 'LocalFree', PTR_WIN32API_TYPE, PTR_WIN32API_TYPE)
      or die($^E);

   return $LocalFree->Call($ptr) == 0;
}


sub GetCommandLine {
   state $GetCommandLine = Win32::API->new('kernel32', 'GetCommandLineW', '', PTR_WIN32API_TYPE)
      or die($^E);

   return decode_LPCWSTR($GetCommandLine->Call());
}


# Returns a reference to an array on success. Returns undef and sets $^E on error.
sub CommandLineToArgv {
   my ($cmd_line) = @_;

   state $CommandLineToArgv = Win32::API->new('shell32', 'CommandLineToArgvW', 'PP', PTR_WIN32API_TYPE)
      or die($^E);

   my $cmd_line_encoded = encode('UTF-16le', $cmd_line."\0");
   my $num_args_buf = pack('i', 0);  # Allocate space for an "int".

   my $arg_ptrs_ptr = $CommandLineToArgv->Call($cmd_line_encoded, $num_args_buf)
      or return undef;

   my $num_args = unpack('i', $num_args_buf);
   my @args =
      map { decode_LPCWSTR($_) }
         unpack PTR_PACK_FORMAT.'*',
            ReadMemory($arg_ptrs_ptr, PTR_SIZE * $num_args);

   LocalFree($arg_ptrs_ptr);
   return \@args;
}


{
   my $cmd_line = GetCommandLine();

   say $cmd_line;

   my $args = CommandLineToArgv($cmd_line)
      or die("CommandLineToArgv: $^E\n");

   for my $arg (@$args) {
      say "<$arg>";
   }
}
```

in CmdArgs.pl and run `perl CmdArgs.pl äö.txt`, the cmd window displays

```
perl  CmdArgs.pl äö.txt
<perl>
<CmdArgs.pl>
<äö.txt>
```

I then packaged the CmdArgs.pl with the Par Packer command `pp -o CmdArgs.exe CmdArgs.pl`,
When I run `CmdArgs.exe äö.txt`, the cmd window shows

```
C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\par-5875\cache-622ad9aefc40f2ce41f40707644eb592d3c73c6a/CmdArgs.exe ??.txt
<C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\par-5875\cache-622ad9aefc40f2ce41f40707644eb592d3c73c6a/CmdArgs.exe>
<??.txt>
```

What I want it to show is

```
C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\par-5875\cache-622ad9aefc40f2ce41f40707644eb592d3c73c6a/CmdArgs.exe äö.txt
<C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\par-5875\cache-622ad9aefc40f2ce41f40707644eb592d3c73c6a/CmdArgs.exe>
<äö.txt>
```

Info:

- Win11
- The OS language is simplified Chinese
- The values of `ACP`, `OEMCP` and `MACCP` in the registry `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage` are 936, 936, and 10008.
- I use `chcp 65001` in `cmd` to change the console's CP.

Debugging:

- `Win32::GetConsoleOutputCP()` returns 65001 (UTF-8) as expected.
- `$args->[ $#$args ]` is `3F.3F.2E.74.78.74` (as returned by `sprintf "%vX"`).
- `$cmd_line` is `….2F.43.6D.64.41.72.67.73.2E.65.78.65.20.3F.3F.2E.74.78.74`.
- The memory returned by `GetCommandLineW` is `….2F.0.43.0.6D.0.64.0.41.0.72.0.67.0.73.0.2E.0.65.0.78.0.65.0.20.0.3F.0.3F.0.2E.0.74.0.78.0.74.0`.

### Solution

The problem has been resolved by Roderich Schupp in the commit https://github.com/rschupp/PAR-Packer/commit/d1624b0dd3215d04223378e58c4ce3b0a7c8d36b. Here is the description of the commit:

> myldr/boot.c passes its arguments in argv (except argv[0]) down to the custom perl interpreter using _spawnvp(). But this argv has already been converted to the local code page, so the custom interpreter can't get it back using GetCommandLineW(). Convert myldr/boot.c to use GetCommandLineW() and CommandLineToArgvW() to get the "real" (UTF-16) command line and pass that down via _wspawnvp(). Convert shell_quote() (to escape embedded blanks, double quotes etc in the arguments) from using char to wchar_t.

The current release, version 1.061, does not yet include this commit, you can use it in the following way:

```
Download the tarball, untar it, then build it:
  
  perl Makefile.PL
  make
  make test
  make install
```

Comment: [Works for me.](https://gist.github.com/ikegami/34fa711400c884134dd9b098389cff00) What's your code page? I'm using 65001, but it fails with `Cannot find encoding "cp437"` with other code pages because the decoder wasn't included in the packed file.

Comment: My computer system is Win11, the language is simplified Chinese,
the key values of "ACP", "OEMCP" and "MACCP" in the registry "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage" are 936, 936, and 10008.
In cmd, I use "chcp 65001" to change the console's CP.

Comment: when run 'perl CmdArgs.pl äö.txt', 

65001
70.65.72.6C.20.20.43.6D.64.41.72.67.73.2E.70.6C.20.E4.F6.2E.74.78.74
E4.F6.2E.74.78.74

Comment: 65001
43.3A.5C.55.73.65.72.73.5C.58.75.5C.41.70.70.44.61.74.61.5C.4C.6F.63.61.6C.5C.54.65.6D.70.5C.70.61.72.2D.35.38.37.35.5C.63.61.63.68.65.2D.35.38.31.63.62.31.61.61.38.36.31.36.34.66.32.61.38.64.30.33.32.62.31.61.30.35.39.63.65.34.32.64.33.63.33.30.36.64.39.30.2F.43.6D.64.41.72.67.73.2E.65.78.65.20.3F.3F.2E.74.78.74.A.A
3F.3F.2E.74.78.74.A.A

Comment: The output of `say sprintf "%vX", $GetCommandLine->Call();` is `32.32.32.36.34.32.32.36.34.31.39.31.38`.

Comment: `43.0.3A.0.5C.0.55.0.73.0.65.0.72.0.73.0.5C.0.58.0.75.0.5C.0.41.0.70.0.70.0.44.0.61.0.74.0.61.0.5C.0.4C.0.6F.0.63.0.61.0.6C.0.5C.0.54.0.65.0.6D.0.70.0.5C.0.70.0.61.0.72.0.2D.0.35.0.38.0.37.0.35.0.5C.0.63.0.61.0.63.0.68.0.65.0.2D.0.61.0.63.0.38.0.34.0.31.0.32.0.33.0.39.0.65.0.30.0.37.0.61.0.39.0.61.0.31.0.37.0.35.0.62.0.34.0.62.0.61.0.30.0.66.0.37.0.33.0.64.0.66.0.66.0.62.0.36.0.36.0.35.0.34.0.63.0.38.0.62.0.30.0.39.0.37.0.65.0.2F.0.43.0.6D.0.64.0.41.0.72.0.67.0.73.0.2E.0.65.0.78.0.65.0.20.0.3F.0.3F.0.2E.0.74.0.78.0.74.0`

Comment: `43.0.3A.0.5C.0.55.0.73.0.65.0.72.0.73.0.5C.0.58.0.75.0.5C.0.41.0.70.0.70.0.44.0.61.0.74.0.61.0.5C.0.4C.0.6F.0.63.0.61.0.6C.0.5C.0.54.0.65.0.6D.0.70.0.5C.0.70.0.61.0.72.0.2D.0.35.0.38.0.37.0.35.0.5C.0.63.0.61.0.63.0.68.0.65.0.2D.0.61.0.63.0.38.0.34.0.31.0.32.0.33.0.39.0.65.0.30.0.37.0.61.0.39.0.61.0.31.0.37.0.35.0.62.0.34.0.62.0.61.0.30.0.66.0.37.0.33.0.64.0.66.0.66.0.62.0.36.0.36.0.35.0.34.0.63.0.38.0.62.0.30.0.39.0.37.0.65.0.2F.0.43.0.6D.0.64.0.41.0.72.0.67.0.73.0.2E.0.65.0.78.0.65.0` and `3F.0.3F.0.2E.0.74.0.78.0.74.0`

Comment: See the `3F.0.3F.0` in the first block, the one returned by `GetCommandLineW`? That's the UTF16-le encoding of the two characters `??`. That means `GetCommandLineW` is returning the wrong value. Why? I have no idea. But it has nothing to do with any of the code you posted. Sorry, I can't help you further.

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you, but I'm only a beginner in perl. The two trailing LF in '3F.3F.2E.74.78.74.A.A' is because I'm used to following text with line breaks. I actually used `sprintf "%vX", $args->[ $#$args ]. "\n\n"`.